# How to place text next to an image centred?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

Sorry, I know this is a very basic question, but I can't figure out how to put text next to an image centred vertically. I have searched up how to do it, and tried several different ways, but I can't seem to find one that works. I'm thinking maybe I've made a mistake I keep overlooking in my code. I'm very new, and just wanted to see how much I could apply what I've learnt. Thank you, this is my code.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/03/08/50/paper-1074131_1280.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

  height: 100%;
  opacity: 75%;

}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}



.image {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  height: 20px;
  width:35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.webtitle {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home - Historically Speaking</title>
  <link href="D:\Programming\HTML\First Website\syle1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="Header">
      <div class="Logo">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Cm5P5vP.jpeg" width="250" height="200" align="left"/>
      </div>
      <div class="webtitle">
        <p> Historically Speaking </p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't write class with capital letter, correct Header to header :) done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `vertical-align: middle;` at all, the flex settings of the container are sufficient for what you want, you just need to be careful about the class name: `header` vs. `Header` - case sensitive...:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/03/08/50/paper-1074131_1280.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 75%;
}

.Header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 35px;
}

.webtitle {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home - Historically Speaking</title>
  <link href="D:\Programming\HTML\First Website\syle1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Header">
    <div class="Logo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Cm5P5vP.jpeg" width="250" height="200" align="left" />
    </div>
    <div class="webtitle">
      <p> Historically Speaking </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah changing the capital worked. Woops

Answer (score 1):

First of correct your class name as .Header into your stylesheet. Secondly, give the height to your Header and display the .webtitlt as flex and Justify content to center

```
    .webtitle {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;


}

.Header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was the typo, thanks for your help